# How to fix "ENOENT: no such file or directory, chdir 'project-name'" when initializing a Vue Native project?

Tags: react-native, vue.js, npm, native, vue-native

I'm trying:

`vue-native init test-project`

And I'm getting this output:

Using globally installed expo-cli 3.0.10

Creating Vue Native project project-new

- Creating project with expo-cli

> [09:09:29] --name: argument is required in non-interactive mode. √
>   Created project with expo-cli
>
> (node:9072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such
>   file or directory, chdir 'project-new'
>       at process.chdir (internal/process/main_thread_only.js:31:12)
>       at installPackages (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-native-cli\src\index.js:182:11)
>       at createExpoProject (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-native-cli\src\index.js:123:3)
>       at init (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-native-cli\src\index.js:101:5)
>       at Command. (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-native-cli\src\index.js:69:7)
>       at Command.listener (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-native-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:315:8)
>       at Command.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Command.parseArgs (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-native-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:651:12)
>       at Command.parse (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-native-cli\node_modules\commander\index.js:474:21)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\vue-native-cli\src\index.js:81:9)
>   (node:9072) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
>   function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
>   not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1) (node:9072) [DEP0018]
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I've already installed **React Native CLI**, **Expo CLI**, and **Vue Native CLI**. I tried to solve the issue by updating `npm` but it did not work.
Also when I run:

`vue-native init test-project --no-crna`

it is ok and no errors appear.